# Is there an C++/Winapi equivalent to slmgr.vbs /skms

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In `cmd` you can call `c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms <host>` to set your KMS Server host address. Is it possible to do the same thing in the Win32 API using C++? I have already done some research and found this:

[image]

Is the `ServerName` string what I'm looking for?

Comment: Its probably either the windows name of the server, IP address or fqdn.

Comment: Yes, there is a Windows API equivalent. This is immediately obvious, once you look at the tool you are asking about. It's a VBScript, that launches the VBScript interpreter. The interpreter runs on top of the Windows API, and will eventually call down into it. I'm not sure the question you asked is the question you meant to ask, though. Besides, don't post screenshots of text. Post text.

Comment: It makes sense. Then my Question is: How to implement slmgr.vbs /skms in C++ as an winapi call and not with system()

Comment: All of the properties of `Win32_WindowsProductActivation` are read-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Licensing API's are available via slc.dll / `Slpublic.h`, for example [SLSetCurrentProductKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/slpublic/nf-slpublic-slsetcurrentproductkey):

```
HRESULT SLSetCurrentProductKey(
  HSLC       hSLC,
  const SLID *pProductSkuId,
  const SLID *pProductKeyId
);
```

See [slpublic.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/slpublic/) for more details.

To change the KMS server address I think you need to change it in the registry (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform`) and then call [SlActivateProduct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/slpublic/nf-slpublic-slactivateproduct):

```
HRESULT SLActivateProduct(
  HSLC                            hSLC,
  const SLID                      *pProductSkuId,
  UINT                            cbAppSpecificData,
  const PVOID                     pvAppSpecificData,
  const SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER *pActivationInfo,
  PCWSTR                          pwszProxyServer,
  WORD                            wProxyPort
);
```

Unfortunately these bits are not exactly well documented...